# Magento form block called but functions not accessible in phtml

Tags: magento

I have a block

```
app/code/local/Company/Club/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Form.php
class Company_Club_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    public function getSubmitUrl()
    {
        die; //this is never reached
        return $this->getUrl('company_club/Customer/Save');
    }
}
```

I call it in my controller :

```
public function AddAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('company_club/adminhtml_edit_form'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

and it refers to a layout

```
<company_club_customer_add>
    <update handle="main_club_update"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="company_club/adminhtml_edit_form" name="addClubCustomer"/>
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>Club/Customer/Add.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</company_club_customer_add>
```

with phtml well displayed and calling

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl(); ?>" method="POST" name="formCustomer" id="formCustomer">
```

When I die my code in getSubmitUrl(), it is not dying, so not called, but when I die in a blank constructor of my form class, it is dying, so the form is well instanciated.
What did I missed to call this function from phtml to form class?

Answer (score 0):

I did an ugly fix, but I can't detect modifications from controller with this :

```
$form = new Company_Club_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Form();
<?php echo $form->getSubmitUrl(); ?>
```